# ASSIMP not loading Textures - OpenGL in Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, opengl

I ran the [sample code](http://assimp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/assimp/trunk/samples/SimpleOpenGL/) given in ASSIMP site with fewer modifications to load a sample DAE model (duck). But it doesn't load with its texture. This was tested in Visual C++ 2008

[image]

Code: http://pastebin.com/LsYkzANb

---

But I wanted this to be working on Qt. So I converted this code to work in Qt.

This gave me the following output. It look white and still no texture.

[image]

Code: http://pastebin.com/dkMKDmV2

---

**NOTE**: In Qt, the equivalent for glutSwapBuffers(), QGLWidget::swapBuffers() created a flickering effect and I removed the line.

---

I tested with a DAE (Collada) model download from google sketchup 3D store. This shows colors but the materials look somewhat transparent! (Light brown area shows the color bands behind it as well)

[image: Light brown area shows the color bands behind it as well]

Please be kind enough to go through the codes above, I've simplified it to the maximum.

Answer (score 2):

> But it doesn't load with its texture.

Meshes don't have textures. Meshes can have texture coordinates, but they don't have textures in the mesh file itself. And since you don't load a texture or bind one or anything, a texture will not magically appear by itself.

Asset Importer is just a mesh loader. It doesn't load textures.

> This gave me the following output.

That looks like your winding order is wrong. You turn on face culling based on mesh properties, but you never really do anything more than that. You don't check what the winding order is (assuming Asset Importer knows the winding order).

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will do some research on that. :-)